# Is there a better way to combine these arrays?

Tags: php, array, php5

Is there a better way to do this kind of array combination with a PHP native function like `array_combine`?  I'm trying to improve my skills, and at certain points I note that I am using too many nested `foreach` for almost everything.

**Using PHP 5.4**

```
   $array = Array(
      'GroupName' => 'Emilio',
      'Moduleid' => Array(
          0 => 15,
          1 => 12,
          2 => 9,
          3 => 1,
          4 => 11,
          5 => 10
      ),
      'Permission' => Array(
          15 => 'W',
          12 => 'R',
          14 => 'W',
          9 => 'W',
          1 => 'R',
          13 => 'W',
          11 => 'W',
          10 => 'R'
      )
  );


  foreach ($array['Moduleid'] as $value) {
    foreach ($array['Permission'] as $key1 => $value1) {
      if ($value == $key1) {
        $result[$key1] = $value1;
      }
    }
  }
  $newArray = array(
      'GroupName' => $array['GroupName'],
      'ModulePermission' => $result
  );
  unset($array);

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($newArray);
  echo '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [GroupName] => Emilio
    [ModulePermission] => Array
        (
            [15] => W
            [12] => R
            [9] => W
            [1] => R
            [11] => W
            [10] => R
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this code considerably using the built-in array functions, specifically `array_flip` and `array_intersect_key`.

```
$newArray = array(
    'GroupName' => $array['GroupName'],
    'ModulePermission' => 
        array_intersect_key($array['Permission'], 
            array_flip($array['Moduleid'])
        )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) can be droped one `foreach`

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array['Permission'] as $key => $value) {
  if (in_array($key, $array['Moduleid'])) {
     $result[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```